# get class from java.util.List<SomeType>

Tags: java, reflection

how to get class from this expression java.util.List

Comment: Im afraid you cant as generic types apply only at compile time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want to know the template class of the List at run time, and the short answer is: you can't. Java generics are used only at compile time: the template arguments are erased before byte code is generated. This is called "[type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)".

Answer (score 7):

If your `List` is defined with a concrete type param, like for example:

```
private class Test {
   private List<String> list;
}
```

then you can get it via reflection:

```
Type type = ((ParameterizedType) Test.class.getDeclaredField("list")
     .getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

However, if the type is not known at compile time, it is lost due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Class<List<Foo>> cls = (Class<List<Foo>>)(Object)List.class
```